# delete view and add another one

Tags: android, android-spinner

> I need to add view to the `layout` when the user chooses something in drop down list.

Here is my code for `spinner`,

```
years={"0 Years","1 Years","2 Years","3 Years","4 Years","5 Years", ... }
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Initially, the `layout` for "0 Years" will be displayed. When the user changes it, the layout related to that item should be displayed. How can I do it dynamically.I have separate `xml` files for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any view and container (should be ViewGroup like - RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc) then you can use following method :

```
public void replaceView(View view){

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container_id);

    if(container.getChildCount() == 0){
        container.addView(view);
    }else{
        container.removeView(container.getChildAt(0));
        container.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Call that in following way :

```
    replaceView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_view_layout, null));
```